# I have a news app, which fetches rss feed through a cron every hour. As the list of files (URLs) it has to fetch is in 100's it gets stuck

Tags: rss, feed, google-news

I have a news app, which fetches rss feed through a cron every hour. As the list of files (URLs) it has to fetch is in 100's it gets stuck. Is it possible to write a cron script, which is conditional, like fetching only 10 at a time from the list of 100's and run

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply by adding a timestamp field in database. Which update on every fetch. So when your url fetch by cron its update the last fetch time. Then you can make a query which fetch the urls according to last fetched time in DESC order and Limit 10.

So only 10 urls fetched which is not fetch from a long time. I think this will solve your problem.